# How to design a MySql Table for a Tag Cloud?

Tags: mysql, database-design, tag-cloud

I have articles on my site, and I would like to add tags which would describe each article, but I'm having problems with design mysql table for tags. I have two ideas:

1. each article would have field "tags", and tags would be in format: "tag1,tag2,tag3"
2. create other table called tags with fields: tag_name, article_id

So when I want tags for article with ID 1, I would run

```
SELECT ... FROM tags WHERE `article_id`=1;
```

But, I would also like to know 3 most similar articles by comparing tags, so if I have article which has tags "php,mysql,erlang", and 5 articles with tags: "php,mysql", "erlang,ruby", "php erlang", "mysql,erlang,javascript", I would choose 1., 3. and 4., since those 3 have most same tags with main article.

Also other question, what is the best way to get 10 "most used tags" ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Generally, for this kind of many-to-many relationship, there are three tables :

- The "`article`" table

  - primary key = id
- The "`tag`" table

  - primary key = id
  - contains the data of each tag :

    - name, for example
- A "`tags_articles`" table, which acts as a join table, and contains only :

  - `id_article` : foreign key that points to an article
  - `id_tag` : foreign key that points to a tag

This way, there is no duplication of any tag's data : for each tag, there is one, and only one, line in the `tag` table.

And, for each article, you can have several tags (i.e. several lines in the `tags_articles` table) ; and, of course, for each tags, you can have several articles.

Getting a list of tags for an article, with this idea, is a matter of an additionnal query, like :

```
select tag.*
from tag
    inner join tags_articles on tag.id = tags_articles.id_tag
where tags_articles.id_article = 123
```

Getting the three "most similar" articles would mean :

- select articles that have tags that the first article has
- only use those which have the most important number of identical tags

Not tested, but an idea might be something that would look like this :

```
select article.id, count(*) as nb_identical_tags
from article
    inner join tags_articles on tags_articles.id_article = article.id
    inner join tag on tag.id = tags_articles.id_tag
where tag.name in ('php', 'mysql', 'erlang')
      and article.id <> 123
group by article.id
order by count(*) desc
limit 3
```

Basically, you :

- select the articles ids for each tag that's present on your initial article

  - as there's an inner join, if an article in the DB has 2 tags that match the `where` clause, without the `group by` clause, there would be two lines for that article
  - of course, you don't want to re-select the article you already had -- which means it has to be excluded.
- but, as you use `group by article.id`, there will be only one line per article

  - but you'll be able to use `count`, to find out how many tags each article has in common with the initial one
- then, it's only a matter of sorting per number of tags, and getting only the third three lines.

Comment: yes, but you didn't answer my main question, how to get 3 most similar articles ?

Comment: @mfolnovich : I've edited my answer a couple of times, to add more informations about the design ; and, then, seeing your comment, I re-edited, to add a possible idea of solution to get the 3 most similar articles.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you'll want to use Pascal MARTIN's suggestion about the table design.

As for finding similar articles, here's something to get you started.  Given that @article_id is the article you want to find matches for, and @tag1, @tag2, @tag3 are the tags for that article:

```
SELECT article_id, count(*)
FROM tags_articles
WHERE article_id <> @article_id
AND tag_id IN (@tag1, @tag2, @tag3)
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**yes, but you didn't answer my main question, how to get 3 most similar articles?**

Answer:
Just look for the same tag ids in the merged table (tags_articles). Gather them and create a pattern.

For example:
Article 1 has tags: 1,2
Article 2 has tags: 2,3,4
Article 5 has tags: 6,7,2
Article 7 has tags: 7,1,2,3

If you want the 3 most similar articles for article 1, you have to look for the tags 1,2. You'll find Article 7 is most similar and 2 and 5 have some similarities.