# How to create Category from one table Colums in MySQL Result

Tags: php, html, mysql

The thing is, I have one table with lots of post. 
I want to Create some Category Like,

```
 - Miley Cyrus 
 - Tylor Swift
 - Celvin Harris
 - Ellie Goulding
```

I want to create Category From just one table, without creating lots of table. Is that possible anyway?

Every category will have various writings. Don't want ID based category. Anyone Please suggest me best possible way to do it. If you have any other Idea I'll appreciate that too.

Comment: so basically, implement a tag cloud?

Comment: You mean, I have to create a query where I put name of the category and If that match It will show the result?

Comment: what Marc's talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602957/how-to-design-a-mysql-table-for-a-tag-cloud - *n'est-ce pas?* Least, I think so.

Comment: don't ask us, you're the one who knows what you want. you need to explain that to us.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just found that on google search. Thanks though.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry, But, I am not expert as you are so I'm confused and also don't know how to do things. Just searching for help from loyal public like you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to just add a column category and then a 'WHERE category = "Miley Cyrus"' (or a GROUP BY). But that would not be a good solution. You should make a second Table for the category in the style of id => name, and then link the id in your current table. If you don't do, you will soon have "Miley Cyrus","miley cyrus","Miley cyrus" ... as category.

Comment: That is helpful. Thanks mate @Doktor OSwaldo